# changing layout for two orientations for a view from interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

is it possible to set the layout for a view for landscape and portrait orientations from interface builder (XCode 4.1)? I'm asking this question because when I set the layout for portrait, and then change view orientation to landscape and re-set the layout again according to landscape, it will keep with the last layout for landscape orientation !! that means, when I switch back to portrait orientation the layout does not change.

any solution to this problem from IB ?

EDIT:

I understood the idea now, so IB will give you limited flexibility for playing with my view in both orientations, it's limited because I can't produce a fully new layout for my view for each orientation from IB, for example, If I have six `UIButtons` (with their shadow image views) placed on a portrait orientation as in the following screenshot: [image]

and giving each button and the shadow image view all resizing masks as in this screenshot:

[image]

the result in landscape will be messed up as in this screenshot:

[image]

so I have two questions:

1) is it possible to set auto-resizing for these objects (from IB) so that the landscape view will match the portrait one ? if yes how ?

2) can I design (from IB) a completely different layout for landscape (without affecting the original layout in portrait) as in the following screenshot:

[image]

If i can't, I think the solution would be to make a new view from code, is that true ?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To automatically change the layout of your view in interface builder, you have to set the autoresizing mask option of all graphical objects of your view. You can either do it programmatically like :

```
myObj.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Or with Interface builder in the Size Inspector tab of each object. You should see something like this :

[image]

When the line is red, it means the margin (**regarding the object container**) will stay the same if device orientation change. In other case, the margin will change to adapt the object placement in the view container.

Unlikely, when a row is in NOT in red, it means the size of teh object will stay the same in all device orientations, else the size will be modified (useful for background image for example)

So, in the example above the object size will not change, and the left and top margin will not change either regarding its container.

Hope this is clear enough. Do not hesitate to react in case it's not clear

*EDIT*

You can check the result of your resizing mask without re-compiling the application simply by doing the trick below :

- Select the uiviewcontroller main view (self.view)
- Go to the Attributes Inspector
- In section "Simulated Metrics" you should see an 'Orientation' Item
- Switch off and on from 'Portrait' to 'Landscape' to see the resulted view

*EDIT1*

If I correctly understand what you means, I think you can do it this way :

[image]

Placing your button and your shadow image view in a view container. Then set the view container autoresizing as you are doing right know for your button and lock the button and image view size/margins regarding this view container.

That should work.

Comment: thank you so much for your thorough clarification. However, please look at my (EDIT) above in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem of IB of course. There's just no built-in mechanism for switching to completely different layout on orientation change.

If your objects (button/shadow) are of different sizes then you have to group them into views as @Niko said for autoresizing masks to work correctly.

Comment: the objects are not of different sizes. so to completely switch to a new different layout on orientation change, I should return back to code and make a new view for that layout ?

Comment: You can design two separate views for portrait and landscape orientations (in IB), add them both to your top view (in viewDidLoad for example) and then show/hide appropriate subview on orientation change.

Comment: sorry mifki, i did not get the idea, how to add the two views in viewDidLoad to top views? and If I did that (creating a second different view on orientation change), then, I have to create (for ex.) two buttons labeled (1) and two buttons (labeled 2), etc... up to (6) according to my screenshot above, which means doubling the functionality for each button (considering that each button fires an IBAction method), which in turn produces much redundant code. so what's the best scenario for that in your opinion ?

Comment: No, no! Of course you can connect as many buttons to single IBAction as you want. So you have your view controller and its view (I call it top view). Keep it empty and create two separate views in IB for each orientation with buttons connected to the same methods. Then in viewDidLoad do [self.view addSubview:] for two views and show/hide them according to current orientation.

Comment: nice clarification mifki, can i connect more than one uibutton to the same IBOutlet too ?

Comment: Of course no:) Many objects can send one message (because it's actually just a selector name). But one outlet can't be connected to more than one object.

Comment: But you can create IBOutletCollection instead ;) For more details, please check this tuto : http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/